# Searching a series of text in one data frame into another data frame

Tags: r

I want to search a series of splitted text in one data frame into another data frame and if found assign score to them.

```
a= c("inter","cde",'c','d','e', NA)
b= c("travel","dfgh",'d','f','g', 'h',NA)
c= as.data.frame(rbind(a,b))
```

we have data frame c where we have 3 rows as mentioned above. I have another data frame which contains as below

```
  e= c("cdes")
  f= c("dfgk")
  l=c(“cdsc”)
  o=c(“dfvv”)
  g= as.data.frame(rbind(e,f,l,o))
```

So for "cde" splitted into c,d,e,NA in c data frame. for "cde" the actual name is inter. Now i want to search c then d then e which is splitted from "cde" in data frame g. If c is found in a row in g then in the same row search d and e and assign score 100 adjacent to all. When NA comes break the loop and goto next row search i.e for d,f,g.

Output should be

```
  V0        V      V1  Score1   V2  Score2  V3  Score3   V4   Score4     V5
 inter     cde      c   100%     d   100%   e    100%    NA    0%       cdes
 travel    dfgh     d   100%     f   100%   g    100%    h     0%       dfgk
```

So in the output all scoring is done and it also gives the matching row from data frame g where the matching has been perfomed. The more matching one from data frame g should come under V5

Comment: Please show what your final result should look like. Also do not put quotation marks around NA if it is meant to mean missing and not to be a string.

Comment: Final output is if c is found then give it a score of 100% the goto the next find d and if found then again assign it 100% score and so on. All scores should be in a new adjacent column. Hope this helps. However c, d, e are the same name when combined splitted into 3 using concat.split now this individually is being searched in another data frame which has cde. This is how the process is.

Comment: What @Elin is saying is that you should actually show what the final output is supposed to look like, not just explain it.  Please write an example of the output dataframe.

Comment: Is there any reason why your data has to be in a dataframe with two rows and multiple columns, rather that one column for `Values`, and in the output one for `Values` and one for `Score`? I ask because it would probably be easier in long format.

Comment: I am pretty much fine with the above scenario may main ask is to get the scoring to see matching accuracy.

Comment: Two more questions: 1) You've included `"NA"`. Do you mean `NA`, i.e. not a character string? 2) Do you absolutely have to have `100%`, or is `100` also okay, i.e. an integer instead of a character string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
aux =apply(c,2,function(x){              # Run function for each column of c
  aux=rep("0%",nrow(g))                  # Create adjacent column with all 0%
  for (i in 1:nrow(g)){                  # For each row of g
    if (grepl(x[i],g[i,],fixed = TRUE)){ # If the letter is found in the text
      aux[i] = "100%"                    # update the 0% with 100%
    }
  }
  cbind(x,aux)                           # join 'c' column to the % column
})

dim(aux)=c(nrow(g),ncol(c)*2)            # reshape the results dimension

> aux
     [,1] [,2]   [,3] [,4]   [,5] [,6]   [,7] [,8]
[1,] "c"  "100%" "d"  "100%" "e"  "100%" "NA" "0%"
[2,] "d"  "100%" "f"  "100%" "g"  "100%" "h"  "0%"
```

*note* I made the code generalized for any `nrow` and `ncol`

You can add the names with

```
colnames(aux)=c(rbind(paste0("V",1:(ncol(aux)/2)),
                      paste0("Score",1:(ncol(aux)/2))))
```

**edit**

I don't really understand the point of part of your code... why do you need `o` and `l` ??? Still, this should give you the result you want.

```
g = as.data.frame(rbind(e,f),stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
c = as.data.frame(rbind(a,b)) 

aux =apply(c[,-(1:2)],2,function(x){                      # Run function for each column of c
  print(x)        
  aux=rep("0%",nrow(g))                          # Create adjacent column with all 0%
  for (i in 1:nrow(g)){                          # For each row of g
    is_it_in = grepl(x[i],g[i,],fixed = TRUE)
    if (ifelse(is.na(is_it_in),FALSE,is_it_in)){ # If the letter is found in the text
      aux[i] = "100%"                            # update the 0% with 100%
    }
  }
  cbind(x,aux)                                   # join 'c' column to the % column
})

dim(aux)=c(nrow(g),(ncol(c)-2)*2)                # reshape the results dimension
res = cbind(c[,1:2],aux,g)                       # Join everything
names(res) = c("V0","V",c(rbind(paste0("V",1:(ncol(res)/2)),
                           paste0("Score",1:(ncol(res)/2)))))[-(ncol(res)+1)]

> res
      V0    V V1 Score1 V2 Score2 V3 Score3   V4 Score4   V5
a  inter  cde  c   100%  d   100%  e   100% <NA>     0% cdes
b travel dfgh  d   100%  f   100%  g   100%    h     0% dfgk
```

Output coming as when l and o are included. However ideally only two rows should come as they are the more close match.

```
  V0    V V1 Score1 V2 Score2 V3 Score3   V4 Score4    V5 Score5   V6
 inter  cde  c   100%  d   100%  e   100% <NA>     0% inter     0% cdes
 travel dfgh  d   100%  f   100%  g   100%    h     0%  <NA>     0% dfgk
 inter  cde  c     0%  d     0%  e     0% <NA>     0% inter     0% cdsc
 travel dfgh  d     0%  f     0%  g     0%    h     0%  <NA>     0% dfvv
```

Comment: Running the above codes gives following error "Error in if (grepl(x[i], g[i, ], fixed = TRUE)) { : 
  argument is not interpretable as logical"

Comment: Yeah I forgot to mention: you characters are coded as `factors`. When you define `c` and `g` add `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` at the end. So, for `c`, `c = as.data.frame(rbind(e,f),stringsAsFactors = FALSE)`

Comment: I added that and then only i ran the code still it throws the same error

Comment: @samadrazakhan I just copied and pasted your example data, then copied and pasted boski's code, and everything ran just fine, even with the factors. Have you changed something somewhere, or are you using different data?

Comment: 1) If the code is working for the whole row once and then moving to the next row. As my condition is it first find 'c' in data frame g, once it find that then it finds d which is in the next column but in the same row. Also it find d in 'cde' only not in any other row since c was present there only.Is it working that way?

2) Also could you please highlight me a bit about how the code is working? @gersht

Comment: Also i want the matching row as well from the data frame g like "cde" at last for c,d,e matching. Please guide what needs to appended in code more. @boski

Comment: Also I have NA instead of "NA" so i want to run the code for the row till it finds NA

Comment: @samadrazakhan I have updated the code with explanation

Comment: thanks @boski. I want to run the code for each row till it finds NA in the row that is when it finds NA the loop breaks and run for the next row this is one requirement and next is i also want to bring the row from the data frame we are matching it as column at the last with the matched row like cde adjacent to c,d,e and so on. Please guide.

Comment: @samadrazakhan sorry can't really understand what you are asking. Please update the question and also add what have you tried ( im not going to do your work with you not even trying lol)

Comment: @boski I have updated the question and the output. Hope it clarifies the ask. Yes i tried doing it from the code you mentioned above however when it finds NA it throws logical error. Also i am unable to bring that matching column from data frame g. Please guide.

Comment: There are 4 rows in data frame g , so while matching the more close match seems to be  "cdes" rather than  "cdsc" and hence when matching it will match wihin row containing "cdes" and will throw "cdes" under V5 since it was the most closest match. Does this clarifies the doubt .  May actual data has multiple values close by but i want the most accurate match.

Comment: @boski running the above code with l and o included throws "dfvv" and “cdsc” as well with 0% which ideally should not come. The exact matching is "cdes" and "dfgk" which ideally should come only.

Comment: Updated the output above.